# neo4j - Local cluster HA setup

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing

I was trying to setup a local cluster using Neo4j Enterprise edition on Windows. Followed the steps given in this link(http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#tutorial-local-cluster). But the nodes never came up. Then made slight changes in terms of ip address ( renamed 127.0.0.1 with localhost as well 0.0.0.0 with localhost ), though they dont make much difference. But still not able to bring up the cluster. Any help is appreciated as well as suggest, if I missed anything.

Comment: Just to add, getting this error in the neo4j.log :Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachineProxyFactory$ResponseFuture.get(StateMachineProxyFactory.java:300)
 at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.joinByConfig(ClusterJoin.java:143)
 at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.start(ClusterJoin.java:82)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
 ... 15 more

Comment: Plz share contents of `debug.log` (on 3.0) or `messages.log` (<= 2.3) here.

Comment: Here are the logs :   neo4j.log :
http://pastebin.com/rgGJJm0D

debug.log
http://pastebin.com/0zEKUh10

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start up all 3 instances? The logs indicate that only one instance has been started so far.

The amount of RAM of your machine - according to logs: 3.43 GB - is challenging for running a cluster with 3 instances. Be sure to explicitly set `dbms.memory.pagecache.size`, I'd start off with e.g. `200M`.

Comment: I modified the entry and made it as 200M. also, started all the 3 instances, but in vain. Do we need to modify any other entry, along with the ones mentioned in the link provided. Please suggest